# D8 Search api - taxonomy pages

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

Is there way to replace /taxonomy/term/% on search api views?

I was trying create new indexed views with Content datasource: Categories » Taxonomy term » Term ID but when i visit page, it's always return 404.

Please, any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

One way to facilitate this is to use [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi). You will be able to create views and set vocabulary or terms to use those views instead of the default taxonomy page from core Drupal.